# Stale Element Exception Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, web-crawler, element, expand

I am trying to crawl trip advisor reviews. Some reviews have the `more` link, which displays the entire text of the review when clicked. However, when I imitate the click using Selenium, the DOM changes, which gives me the `Stale Element Exception`. I am trying to work around it by getting the DOM again, but the error still exists. Where am I going wrong?

```
List reviews = driver.findElements(By.className("review"));
for (int x = 0; x < reviews.size(); x++) {
    WebElement element = driver.findElements(By.className("review")).get(x);
    try {
        if (element.findElements(By.className("expandLink")).size() > 0)
            if (element.findElement(By.className("expandLink")).findElement(By.className("ulBlueLinks")).getText().startsWith("More")) {
                element.findElement(By.className("ulBlueLinks")).click();
                if (driver.findElements(By.className("ui_overlay")).size() > 0)
                    driver.findElement(By.className("ui_overlay")).findElement(By.className("ui_close_x")).click();
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    while (driver.findElements(By.className("ui_close_x")).size() > 0)
        driver.findElement(By.className("ui_close_x")).click();
    element = driver.findElements(By.className("review")).get(x);
    String rating = element.findElement(By.className("ui_bubble_rating")).getAttribute("class").split(" ")[1].replaceAll("bubble_", "");
    String review = element.findElement(By.className("entry")).getAttribute("innerHTML").replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "").replaceAll("[,\n]", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same thing, this is due to sometimes problems with DOM elements which are not reachable by selenium causing exception. 
I come with this solution and it worked for me.

http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.in/2012/06/staleelementexception.html

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. However, the error is not because of the click, but rather the following statements after the click, the `String rating`... onwards statements.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the @FindBy annotation for declaring WebElements? Using this annotation, each time you make a call to a WebElement the driver searches the DOM for that WebElement.

This methodology means you only need to declare each element once and a reference to the WebElement is stored. It also allows you to make use of the Page Object Pattern, which will give you clean separation between page and test logic.

Here is a write up on it:

https://www.toptal.com/selenium/test-automation-in-selenium-using-page-object-model-and-page-factory